# Unable to load interstitial ad in unity with ad mob

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Ok I know its a very silly problem but still it is, I used ad mob for monetizing but the problem is that it is not showing interstitial ad(I used test ad IDs for checking), I have write code that it shows ad whenever my game opens. When I run the game in editor it is showing but when I build apk and run it in my android no interstitial ad is shown, also I have used banner ad which is showing at the beginning, below is the code what i have written, both interstitial and banner ads are showing in editor but only banner ad in mobile**

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
public class Admanager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Admanager instance;
    private string  appID = "ca-app-pub-5738770908249133~9238181298";
    private BannerView bannerView;
    private string bannerID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";

    private InterstitialAd fullscreenAd;
    private string fullscreenAdID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        RequestBanner();
        RequestFullScreenAd();
    }
    public void RequestBanner()
    {
        bannerView = new BannerView(bannerID, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);
        bannerView.Show();
    }
    public void HideBanner()
    {
        bannerView.Hide();
    }
    public void RequestFullScreenAd()
    {
        fullscreenAd = new InterstitialAd(fullscreenAdID);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        fullscreenAd.LoadAd(request);
        fullscreenAd.Show();
        
    }
    
    
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to wait some time and check if interstitial ad is loaded.
Here is the code from google dev portal:

```
private void GameOver()
{
  if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded()) {
    this.interstitial.Show();
  }
}
```

Full docs - [Admob_Unity_Interstitial](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/interstitial)